# Get Data from SQL Database and set it to ListView in Android

Tags: android, sql, listview, editor, android-arrayadapter

I want to get data from SQL Server and set it to list.

**1. I already have data in my current Activity. `_I printed it on Logcat_` .**

**2. Now I want to set that data to my list.**

*Basically I have taken a static list of data for the basic view, that I mention there*

***How to set that data to list ?***

Here is my Code that will show content how i did code :

```
public class menus extends Activity {

ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
Editor edit1;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

int i = 0,count = 0;
String[] listOfMenus;
String listdetails;
Connection xyz;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_item);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.menulistblank);

    editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

     /////// This is my Static data that I stored in list.

    String[] values = new String[]{"Adroid Developer",".Net Developer","Java Developer","BA"};

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

         list.setAdapter(adapter); 

                // Object of connection for getting content.
         xyz = MainActivity.conn;

         MyNetworkTask myWebFetch = new MyNetworkTask();
         myWebFetch.execute();

         list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You click "+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}

   //////// ASYNC TASK ////////

private class MyNetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         Log.w("Process completed", "In XXXXXXXX");
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
          Log.w("Process completed", "aaaaaaaaaa");
     }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("Process completed", "In doInBackground..");
        try {
            st = MainActivity.conn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lalit_db;");
            while(rs.next()){

                  // ***** It prints my required data  in Logcat
                Log.w(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3));
                }

            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
 }
}// Main Program Ends..
```

Please tell me what should i do to

set this data of logcat `Log.w(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3));` **in List.**

Comment: Why don't you use json parsing, if you want to load data from external database, that will be more easier.

Comment: Actually I have never use json. And i dont know what is that. Can you give me any link to learn json. @InnocentKiller

Comment: Use this link  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating a list view from SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621800/populating-a-list-view-from-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add strings in values while fetching data

   ```
   st = MainActivity.conn.createStatement();
   rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lalit_db;");
   values=new String[st.getFetchSize()]; //total number of rows
   int index=0;
   while(rs.next()){
     values[index]=rs.getString(2);
     index++;
    // ***** It prints my required data  in Logcat
    Log.w(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3));
   }
   ```
2. Display in onPostExecute()

   ```
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     Log.w("Process completed", "aaaaaaaaaa");
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(menus.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

      list.setAdapter(adapter); 
   }
   ```

**Edit**

add `@Override` annotation to onPostExecute() method

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      Log.w("Process completed", "aaaaaaaaaa");
 }
```

Comment: I have tried that but it gives error like `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(menus.MyNetworkTask, int, int, String[]) is undefined` @Ketan

Comment: try updated answer. replace `this` with `menus.this`.

Comment: Yes sir Its working (not gives any error) but the method `onPostExecute` not get called. Why? check out my question. @Ketan

Comment: Sir I already tried that but it gives error `The method onPostExecute(Long) of type menus.MyNetworkTask must override or implement a supertype method` @Ketan

Comment: now this should work..replace `(Long result)` to `(Void result)`

Comment: Absolutely correct Now that method gets called and gives error `01-06 08:39:36.562: W/Process completed(5522): aaaaaaaaaa
01-06 08:39:36.662: D/AndroidRuntime(5522): Shutting down VM
01-06 08:39:36.662: W/dalvikvm(5522): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-06 08:39:36.722: E/AndroidRuntime(5522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 08:39:36.722: E/AndroidRuntime(5522): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 08:39:36.722: E/AndroidRuntime(5522):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
` What should i do sir. @Ketan

Comment: As you say Array "values" is null. What will be the solution for it?
@Ketan

Answer (score 0):

if you want multicolumn ListView  , try this :

```
public void fillList(ResultSet rs,ListView list_head,ListView list,int layout,int to[],String columns[],String titles[]) 
{       
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist, mylist_title;
    ListAdapter adapter_title, adapter;
    HashMap<String, String> map1, map2;

    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    mylist_title = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    /**********Display the headings************/
    map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)  
        map1.put(columns[i], titles[i]);
    mylist_title.add(map1);

    try 
    {
        adapter_title = new SimpleAdapter(context, mylist_title,layout,columns, to);
        list_head.setAdapter(adapter_title);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("Error1","" + e.getMessage()); 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /**********Display the contents************/





    try 
    {
    while(rs.next())
    {           
        map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)  
            map2.put(columns[i], rs.getObject(columns[i]).toString());
        mylist.add(map2);
    }
} catch (SQLException e1) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.w("Error2","" + e1.getMessage()); 
    e1.printStackTrace();
}



    try 
    {
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, mylist, layout,columns, to);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.w("Error3","" + e.getMessage()); 
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply but I already solved the issue. :)