# new listview item creation, which includes sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have an actity in which I can add data to a SQLite table, like this [addActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cUxx.png)

with class

```
public class addActivity extends Activity {
private Button btn, btnGo, btnDeleteMeal;
private DbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private ArrayList<String> mealId = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> mealName = new ArrayList<String>();
private ListView userList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_meal);
    userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView8);
    mHelper = new DbHelper(this);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    displayData();
    super.onResume();
}
private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
    mealId.clear();
    mealName.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {               mealId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper._ID)));                mealName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MEAL_NAME)));                
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());        
    DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(NewMealActivity.this, mealId, mealName, mealProtein, mealFat, mealCarbohydrate, mealCalories, mealWeight);
    userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
    mCursor.close();
}
```

DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DB_MEAL_NAME="meal";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="meal_list";
public static final String _ID ="_id";
public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,  DB_MEAL_NAME, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+
            _ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
            MEAL_NAME+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}
I want, when I click on button opens new activity and create listview item, which includes a table with the date of the addition like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4k0j.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating a list view from SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621800/populating-a-list-view-from-sqlite-database)

Comment: No, it is not. I am populate a list view from SQLite Database in addActivity, but I want to set whole table data (addActivity) to another activity listview item

Comment: Didn't understood what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Something like a diary: I am adding data to SQLite table in one activity and I present in the form of one record in another activity

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I want, when I click on button opens new activity and create listview item, which includes a table with the date of the addition